# Weakly referenced object no longer exists kivy

Tags: python, kivy

When I run the code it shows the error ' weakly referenced object no longer exists'. Label object 'lbl' is weakly referenced .How could I solve this issue?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class Audioplayer(App):
 def build(self):
     layout = GridLayout(cols = 2 )
     btn = Button(text = "Arey Band kar")
     lbl = Label(text = "gaana ban Raha hai")
    
     music = SoundLoader.load("prb.mp3")
    
     if music:
         music.play()
    
     layout.add_widget(btn)
     layout.add_widget(lbl)
    
     return layout
    
Audioplayer().run()
```

Comment: In which line does it show that?

Comment: It isn't mentioned in the error I get

Comment: Then please use the debugger and step line over line